# Counting the maximum number of elements of a subset

Tags: combinatorics

Set the universal set as $$U=\{x\in\Bbb{Z} \mid 0 < x < 251\}$$ and let's name one of its subsets as $S$:

$$S= \{x\in S \mid\ if \ x \in S, \ 3x \notin S\}$$ Then how many elements can this set $S$ have?

Comment: That's not a well defined subset.

Comment: what has been tried ? what are your thoughts ?

Comment: Are you asking for the maximum of these, since if $S$ is such a set, any subset also has the same property?

Comment: A maximum-sized set $S\subseteq\{1,\dots,250\}$ such that $x\in S\implies3x\notin S$ is the set of all numbers in $\{1,\dots,250\}$ of the form $3^{2n}a$ where $n$ is a nonnegative integer and $a$ is an integer not divisible by $3.$ The number of numbers in $S$ is $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left\lceil\frac23\left\lfloor\frac{250}{3^{2n}}\right\rfloor\right\rceil=167+18+2+0+\cdots=187.$$

Answer (score 1):

A greedy algorithm is your friend here.  Take the numbers starting from $250$ downwards until you find a problem.  It comes at $249/3=83$.  Then you can't use any number from $83$ down to ???  Once you don't use those, you can use $\ldots$